# Button visibility according to actvities

Tags: android

I have three activities A.B and C. I have a button in activity C. My requirement  is that the button should only visible when going from activity B to C. The button should be invisble when going from A to C. Please help me.

Comment: You can pass int flag whether activity C opened by A or B

Comment: @Khemraj bro can yoy give me some hint or eample?

Comment: Wait a bit i write some sample for you.

Comment: @Khemraj ok bro.

Comment: I wrote full code for you :)

Comment: @Khemraj bro you are super life saver.Thank mate.

Comment: @Khemraj bro the button is showing from both activity. Is there anything to do with visibility of button in xml?

Comment: My mistake just change FROM_B value to 2 in class C.

Comment: By mistake it remained 1 value in FROM_A and FROM_B

Comment: @Khemraj bro if there is more than thee activity what will be the values for FROM_D,FROM_E etc...?

Comment: Simple, values should be unique because this work as keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Activity A**

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
        // TODO: 5/5/2018 consider findViewById 
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, C.class);
                intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA, FROM_A);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Activity B**

```
public class B extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
        // TODO: 5/5/2018 consider findViewById
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
                intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA, FROM_B);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Activity C**

```
public class C extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    public static int FROM_A = 1;
    public static int FROM_B = 2;
    public static String KEY_EXTRA = "KEY_EXTRA";

    int activityStartedFrom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
        // TODO: 5/5/2018 consider findViewById
        activityStartedFrom = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_EXTRA, FROM_B);
        button.setVisibility(activityStartedFrom == FROM_B ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```